# Apache Cordova: How to implement custom iOS AppDelegate correctly?

Tags: ios, cordova

I am developing a hybrid iOS app, consisting of native parts (storyboards, Swift code), Cordova/Phonegap and Meteor as the server back-end.

I know that there's a documentation on embedding Cordova's web views into native apps in the Cordova docs:

http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/edge/guide_platforms_ios_webview.md.html#iOS%20WebViews

According to this documentation, all you have to do is to create an own view and call this:

```
CDVViewController* viewController = [CDVViewController new];
viewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480);
[myView addSubview:viewController.view];
```

However, I can see in the standard Cordova projects that the standard Cordova AppDelegate is doing much more than this. For instance, it sets up a NSHTTPCookieStorage and also implements code to send information back from the native side to the web app.

I did not want to lose this functionality, which I assume is important. Hence, instead of "just" adding a view to one of my view controllers, I derived my own AppDelegate (Swift) class from the standard Cordova AppDelegate (Objective-C) class like this:

```
@UIApplicationMain
class MyCustomAppDelegate: AppDelegate {

override func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject : AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
  self.viewController = MainViewController()
  return true
}

}
```

MainViewController is Cordova's standard view controller, so I also tried to re-use this to be as close to the standard as possible.

In the view that embeds the Cordova web view, I am attaching the web view to the parent view like this:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
  super.viewDidLoad()
  let cordovaViewController = [... code to get the web view controller set by Cordova's app delegate]
  cordovaViewController.view.frame = webappView.bounds
  webappView.addSubview(cordovaViewController.view)
}
```

Basically, this works, but I am facing weird behaviour like the web-view jumping out of the borders I have assigned to it in the storyboard as soon as I call plugins like the Cordova camera and return back from the camera view to my web view. In this case, I am seeing the following error message in Xcode's log:

```
Presenting view controllers on detached view controllers is discouraged
```

This warning is actually rendered when the Cordova plugin calls presentViewController on its own view controller like this (from the Cordova code):

```
__weak CDVCamera* weakSelf = self;

[…]

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [weakSelf.viewController presentViewController:cameraPicker animated:YES completion:^{

                weakSelf.hasPendingOperation = NO;

            }];

        });
```

The warning message does not occur if I am using the standard Cordova Xcode project (i.e. without my native part), so I can only guess that my view controller is "floating around" somewhere, unattached to something it should better be „attached" to. But I have no clue what this is.

So I am wondering if anybody has some sample code out there that shows how to embed a Cordova view in a way that keeps all Cordova functionality up and running, but does not break anything.

Thanks in advance for any advice, Tom

EDIT: I now managed to get rid of the error by setting Cordova's view controller as a child view controller of my embedding container like this:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
  super.viewDidLoad()
  let cordovaViewController = ...
  self.addChildViewController(cordovaViewController)
  cordovaViewController.view.frame = webappView.frame
  webappView.addSubview(cordovaViewController.view)
  cordovaViewController.didMoveToParentViewController(self)
}
```

Yet still, I am asking myself if my way of integrating Cordova is the right way and would appreciate any sample code of existing hybrid apps.

Comment: I am facing a similar issue, I need to use the supportedInterfaceOrientationsFor method in the app delegate. Did you find any solution?